# NASM assembler - unwanted 66 in generated machine code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

- os:windows 10
- cpu:intel core i5-5300U
- architecture:x64

I just started to learn assembly language. I used the online compiler, but today I downloaded NASM. I tried to assemble this simple code that multiplies 10 by 15:

```
mov eax, 0xa
mov edx, 0xf
imul eax, edx
ret
```

An attempt to execute the machine code generated by NASM has failed so I opened this code in *hex editor* and compared it with code generated by [online assembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) that I can successfully execute.

NASM:

```
66 b8 0a 00 00 00 66 ba 0f 00 00 00 66 0f af c2 c3
```

online editor:

```
b8 0a 00 00 00 ba 0f 00 00 00 0f af c2 c3
```

The only differences between these two codes are the unwanted `66`'s in the code generated by NASM. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You forgot to show your `nasm` command but my guess is you assembled it in 16 bit mode. I assume you used `-f bin` so insert `[bits 32]` or `[bits 64]` at the top of your file, as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as Jester suggested. I do not included BITS 64 declaration. Now when I included BITS 64 everything works

Comment: Note that you only ever want this in code that will be assembled with `nasm -fbin` into a flat binary.  If you're going to use `nasm -fwin64`, that sets BITS 64 for you.  Using an explicit `bits 64` lets you make mistakes like assembler 64-bit machine code into a 32-bit object file, and then have weird problems at run-time instead of a nice error message like `push rax`  warning you that it's a register name in 64-bit mode (but that you're *not* assembling 64-bit code).